# Developing Android Applications with an HTC Tattoo Phone

Tags: android, adb, eclipse-adt

Has anyone managed to develop Android Applications using Eclipse on the Windows platform. I understand the ADB needs to recognize specific models of phone and wondered if the Tattoo is supported.

Comment: ADB needs to know about certain manufacturers of phone, not individual models. You should have no problem with an HTC device.

Answer (score 1):

I develop on OS X not Windows, but I have developed with a number of devices including the Tattoo which was recognized immediately by ADB.

Some users have reported issues with Dev Tools, see http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9c57df28e4164737/b20202476f6b02f3

I have not has such problems but my device was a developer unit not a consumer unit.

For the record I have had difficulty getting ADB to recognize a device, and that was an LG 620. I may raise a question here about that in fact.